# What is a good way to correct a missing word in a text?

Tags: etiquette, texting

I was wondering if there are any good shorthand ways to let the receiver of a text know that the previous text was missing a word at a particular position.  For example, if the text is:

> Hey Kim want to today?

and say something like

> 4^meet

to say that "meet" should go after the fourth word.  The above example isn't common and doesn't work for large texts.  I was wondering what the standard protocol is for something like this?

Comment: If you know what word is missing, was it needed? If it was not needed, does it need correcting? If you are making an assumption and want to confirm it, then ask what they mean.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is pretty common to use an asterisk with the surrounding words you wish to add.

> *want to meet today

Note: the asterisk is also commonly placed at the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: I also see (and use) this all the time to correct an error of commission, usually a swipo or auto-(in)correct error.

Answer (score 2):

Close to the other answer, but I've always seen and used

> meet today*

or just

> meet*

The second option can only really be used if it's really obvious where the mistake was. If you don't think it'll be clear, include 1-2 words around the mistake. Bonus points if those words are fairly unique, as it makes identifying that part of the text easier.